# Display rows in database using java

Tags: java, mysql

I was trying to display the rows in the database using Java. My idea is to sort the rows in the database and display them in 3 columns and infinite rows. This is what I have. When I run it, I couldn't see any output. Where did I go wrong?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Rows {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException 
{
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testapp";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);


        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from site order by fname;";


        stmt.execute(sql);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not load database driver!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
            finally 
            {
        if (connection != null) 
                    {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}


}
```

The database table I have is
datas(id int, fname varchar(20)

Comment: You are just fetching the values..not showing them.where you written that code to show ?

Comment: do you get any exceptions? Is your table populated?

Comment: You don't see any output, because you output nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should obtain a `ResultsSet` and iterate through it.

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testapp";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);


    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    //You shouldn't need the semi-colon at the end
    String sql = "select * from site order by fname;";

    //missing piece
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {

        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        System.out.println(id + "\t" + name);
    }
```

Comment: if I have 10 rows,
1 Tiger    4 Chetah    7 Elephant
2 Lion     5 Jaguar    8 Monkey
3 Snake    6 Hyena     9 Donkey
                       10 Cow

Comment: is that the id or the fname your displaying?

Comment: id and fname.
1 Tiger 4 Chetah 7 Elephant in one column

Answer (score 2):

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
 String sql = "select id, fname from site order by fname;";
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next()){
int id=rs.getInt("id");
.............
}
```

Reference: [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)